# Contiously adding to datatable

Tags: c#, for-loop, datatable, oledb

I have the code below that goes out to a database using OleDB and fills a dataset with the information. It then checks to make sure it has something in the dataset, if it does it then addes that dataset to a datatable that is then returned at the end of the function.

```
for (int i = 0; i < UserClassDict[UserName].ControlNumber.Count; i++)
                    {
                        string query = "SELECT * FROM [FNF Taxes] WHERE ControlNumber =" + UserClassDict[UserName].ControlNumber[i] + ";";
                        adapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
                        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
                        adapter.Fill(dataset);

                        if (dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            dt = dataset.Tables[0];
                                                }
                    }
```

My question is this. As you can tell by the for loop that this block is in, it will run numerous times and I would like each of those rows that it pulls from the DB to be added to the datatable. So that when the datatable is returned it has all X amount of rows. However, as it is in the above code-block, the only row that is added to the datatable is the most recent row that was pulled.

Comment: I have a difficulty to understand what is the quetsion.

Comment: The technique used to build this sql is vulnerable to injection attacks. This particular query is likely okay, as it looks like the C# object is a numeric data type, but if other queries you use the same technique to substitute data into the query, you're practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: May be some additional codes could help to help better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DataTable.Merge()`:

```
DataTable dt = null;
for (int i = 0; i < UserClassDict[UserName].ControlNumber.Count; i++)
{
    string query = "SELECT * FROM [FNF Taxes] WHERE ControlNumber =" + UserClassDict[UserName].ControlNumber[i] + ";";
    adapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
    DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(dataset);

    if (dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        if (dt == null)
            dt = dataset.Tables[0].Clone();
        dt.Merge(dataset.Tables[0]);
    }
}
return dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

The most straight forward way I know of is to continue to load the same instance of a `DataTable`. Consider a class that might look like this:

```
private DataTable _dt = new DataTable();

...

private void FillMyDataTable()
{
    ...
    sda.Fill(_dt);
}
```

or in your case, the `DataSet`. Another option is `Merge` which was provided as a solution by DonBoitnott.

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply a Concatenation method at this level **dt = dataset.Tables[0];** ... I would avoid object declaration inside an Iteration... the Loop looks too busy... Also, you can make good use of the `i` in the `for loop` where instead of having something like  `[0],` you'd go for `[i]` .....to allow `dt` to store concatenated data.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can run the query once. You do not have to create all these objects in your loop.

```
              string where = "";
               string query = "SELECT * FROM [FNF Taxes] WHERE ControlNumber = {0};";
               for (int i = 0; i < UserClassDict[UserName].ControlNumber.Count; i++)
               {
                   if(i == UserClassDict[UserName].ControlNumber.Count -1 )
                      where+=UserClassDict[UserName].ControlNumber[i] ;
                   else
                       where += UserClassDict[UserName].ControlNumber[i] + ",";

               }

               adapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(string.Format( query,where), conn);
               DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
               adapter.Fill(dataset);

               if (dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
               {
                   if (dt == null)
                       dt = dataset.Tables[0];
               }
```